# Not getting any AJAX response in Codeigniter 2.x

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 2.x

**My controller function**

```
function remove(){
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    $res = $this->ask_model->remove($id);

    if($res){
        $data = array('msg' => 'Removed');
    } else {
        $data = array('msg' => 'Not removed');
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**NOTE:** I have written `echo json_encode($data)`.

**My model**

```
function remove($inpt){
    $stat = array('stat' => 0);
    $this->db->where('id',$inpt);
    $this->db->update('uploads',$stat);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**AJAX**

```
$(".prv .rmv").click(function () {

    var rmval = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url("user-question-edit/remove"); ?>',
        data: {"id": rmval},
        dataType:'json',
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.msg);
         }
    });

});
```

While performing the above, **my MySQL table is being updated** but console.log says

> POST http://path/to/user-question-edit/remove/ net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

and status showing failed.

[image: Chrome Status]

**What should I do to check the response ?**

**UPDATE:** I mistakenly typed my model function `remove_upload`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
And this worked for me, but the real solution should be inside apache configurations




or you can do this
$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;

 function reply(){
        $msg = $this->Message_model;        
        $insert = $msg->send_message2();
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
die;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following hope you will get helps....

```
function remove(){
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    $res = $this->ask_model->remove($id);

    if($res){
        $data = array('msg' => 'Removed');
    } else {
        $data = array('msg' => 'Not removed');
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And in Ajax make use of `eval()` function.So see response as below:

```
$(".prv.rmv").click(function () { 

    var rmval = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url("user-question-edit/remove"); ?>',
        data: {'id': rmval},
        dataType:'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            var response=eval(data);
            alert(response.msg);
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: My Model Function name is `remove()`. I mistakenly typed it `remove_upload`

Comment: `$(".prv,.rmv").click(function () { //multiple selector separated by comma`  It is not multiple selector. `.rmv` is the child css class of `.prv`. However it works fine if I put only `.rmv` in `$(".rmv")`. **I tried puting `eval` but it doesn't work.**

Comment: did you getting value on alerting `rmval`?